# Can my overly suspicious boyfriend see my info and accounts and more on my laptop or phone?

Tags: wifi

I live at home with a caring but paranoid overly suspicious boyfriend who has unfortunately been burned too many times in life by others. He never believes where I am, always rushes me etc. The 6-7 phone calls when I couldn't grab the phone or was sleeping in the other room also put up red flags. Anyhow this worried me a bit a while ago. He seems harmless now but I was considering trying to leave. I was scared because of how close to home another situation that affected me was. My father committed murder suicide. So this type of behavior had me concerned for my safety at one point and I still really want to get questions answered..
Anyway I was talking to some girlfriends about the behavior on Facebook, asking them not to repeat anything because my safety might be at risk. One day he just told me he knew how I "Backstabbed him" He knew word for word what I said. He felt very hurt and needless to say I was/am a honest person being overly scrutinized! I was frustrated that that he came upon those conversations, the things I said BECAUSE OF HIS OBSESSIVE WORRY ETC!! So he felt used, abused and of coarse now doesn't have any trust and just sees it all wrong.I just want to ask this because I wonder if he somehow got access to my accounts, private info. I might have forgotten to sign out of my email, while using his computer late one night, that links my email to facebook but I'm really not sure and the weirness continues here and there so please tell me, If we share the same wi-fi connection, under the same roof, with a single older router with a  default name, Can he access my pc info and private accounts, like email etc.? We both have our own computers and we both have smartphones too, all used on this Wi-Fi when we are home. I'm trying to see how far this will go and get a clear answer. I'm not a computer wiz but am able to fix things with help and reading. Weird I also realized I was in a home group and must've been out of it because I don't recall setting this up. I don't know too much about this feature but understand its for sharing stuff back and forth so I went to settings and I checked disable access to my files, and other related info. Can you please enlighten me? I think these 2 issues are similar but rather different. I just need to see if there's a way he can view my info and how to know if he is spying.
Thanks,
Dayna

Comment: I don't think this is really a security question. It is more a relationship question, try [interpersonal.se]. As for the security part: it depends how knowledgeable and deterministic he is to find out what you are doing and how knowledgeable you are to protect yourself. Of course, too much protection on your part might be seen as missing trust.

Comment: This is too broad for us to answer regardless, unfortunately.  However, I agree with Steffen and I think you really need to ask about this on interpersonal skills.  BTW, as someone who has helped women stuck in abusive relationships: it sounds like you are in one (even if not physically abusive) and should seriously consider leaving.  People like this rarely change.  Of course that is a bit of a cynical thought, so you should really take this to interpersonal....

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you feel like you are in an unsafe situation seek help immediately.

If a person has access to your email account and you have an account with a third-party website which uses the email for password reset then a person could use this to get into your account (you would however detect this as your password would suddenly be different).

If a person has admin access to your wireless access point they can intercept and read certain traffic if it is not encrypted (if they are highly sophisticated they can make you think it is encrypted when it is not).

As for the homegroup, that can be used to share files so if this isn't something you want to do then you should leave the homegroup.

Ultimately if you don't want this person to have access to your information you cannot co-habitate with them.  If a person of even moderate skill has physical access to your devices he can gather sensitive information from them.